# Interesting behavior of Android camera

Tags: android, camera, settings, camera2

I am not sure how to exactly express this. But you must have noticed that the android camera automatically adjusts the 'look' of the camera preview based on the object it is being pointed at. Like for example, if you point the camera directly at a light, it will darken the surrounding area of the light and make the light appear without blowing out the color. I have fiddled with many of the settings in the camera app but couldn't find any way to stop this automatic adjustment.

So what is this adjustment called really. And can I turn this feature off/on from code?

Comment: The behavior is auto-exposure. You should be able to fiddle around with it using e.g. `CaptureRequest` settings.

Comment: I haven't yet tried in code. But the default camera app seem to have an option to select the exposure. If I put it to the lowest the adjustment is less frequent. But it doesn't seem to be totally locked.

Comment: I found how to lock this behavior. Thanks for mentioning auto-exposure. I have to lock auto-exposure to stop auto re-adjusting.